# wrong image sequence inside my javascript when having pagination of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a web template which have an image gallery , a live sample can be shown on the following [link](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/index.html).

now i modified the above "Latest Work" section paginating, so if you click on an image and the image got displayed inside the jquery slider , then i added a span inside the image as follow:-

[image]

to implement showing the span inside the jquery slider, i modified the touch.jquery.js script's call back function as follow:-

```
        function loadImage(src, callback){
            var img = $('<img>').on('load', function(){
                callback.call(img);
            });

            img.attr('src', src);
 // *******Here is my custom code start ....****
            var allcaptions = $("figure span");


            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".placeholder").each(function (i) {

                    // in each .placeholder, copy its caption's mark-up into it (remove the img first)
                    var caption = allcaptions.eq(i).clone();

                    var t = caption.find("img").attr('data-goto');

                    // caption.append($("<a />", { "text": "test", "href": t }));
                    caption.append("<a href='" + t + "'>test</a>");

                    caption.find("img").remove();
                    $(this).append("<div class='caption'>" + caption.html() + "</div>");
                });
            }, 500
    );
        }
```

now the above will work if the user click on the first image inside the paining section, but if he do some paging then he clicks on an image, then span that will be shown will not be related to the picture.. seems it is related to the way the `.each(function (i)`  works.

now here is a sample of the markup for the paging , on the web page :-

```
<div class="row_2">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Latest Works</h4>
            <div class="pagination2" id="pagin2"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="list_carousel2 responsive">
                    <ul id="carousel2">         
                        <li>
                           <figure><a href="img/page1_bigworks1.jpg" class="thumb"><img  src="img/page1_works1.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span></a></figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <figure><a href="img/page1_bigworks2.jpg" class="thumb"><img  src="img/page1_works2.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span></a></figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <figure><a href="img/page1_bigworks3.jpg" class="thumb"><img  src="img/page1_works3.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span></a></figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <figure><a href="img/page1_bigworks4.jpg" class="thumb"><img  src="img/page1_works4.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span></a></figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <figure><a href="img/page1_bigworks5.jpg" class="thumb"><img  src="img/page1_works5.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span></a></figure>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <figure><a href="img/page1_bigworks6.jpg" class="thumb"><img  src="img/page1_works6.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Lorem ipsum dolore massa</em><img src="img/searchsmall.png" alt=""></span></a></figure>
                        </li>                   
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the markup inside the jquery slider :-

[image]

so can anyone adivce please ?now on another pages i am loading the images without using paging and i did not face this problem.. so i am 100% sure this is related to the paging functionality..

Comment: _"now the above will work if the user click on the first image inside the paining section, but if he do some paging then he clicks on an image, then span that will be shown will not be related to the picture.."_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: is allcaptions.length equal to the number of photos you have?

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev yes the same, but the problem is somehow related to the fact that when you doing paging the order of the li inside the lu will be changed,, that why if i start from the first image it will work, if i do some paging the will get different paging ..

Comment: so can i base the span selection based on the image URL or name rather than based on the sequence as i am currently doing ?

Comment: What about that image variable there? I don't have all the code, but I presume it's the current image. Can you get current image's caption by doing this?
$(img).siblings('span').html()

You can try getting the image from the dom on the click event and then select its neighboring caption

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev so where i need to write this? inside the touch.jquery script ?

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev what i am trying to do is to replace this " var caption = allcaptions.eq(i).clone();" by this " var caption = allcaptions.contains(img.attr('src'));" but currently the later will not shown anything,, but as an idea instead of selecting based on eq(i) to select based on contains(img.attr('src')) will this work in any way ?